# How to specify TCP congestion algorithm to use for my long running rsync process?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, rsync, latency

I have a huge rsync task where I'd like to syncronize file colletion of my workstation and remote server (rsync over ssh). I assume the whole process to take weeks so I don't want to cripple my network for the whole time by increasing latency of the network for all other processes.

I know that if I could persuate the rsync to switch to low priority congestion control (`lp`) it would automatically give most of the network bandwidth to other processes in case of any congestion.

I know that I can load support for the low priority congestion control simply by running `sudo modprobe tcp_lp` and user mode apps are allowed to use it as long it's listed in `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_allowed_congestion_control`.

However, I prefer keeping `cdg` or `vegas` as my default congestion control algorithm. How to get `rsync` (and the underlying `ssh`) to use congestion control algorithm `lp` instead?

My intent is to allow `rsync` to go full speed as long as the network is not used for anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the destination is known, specify the congestion control algorithm as a route option:

```
ip route add <ip_addr>/32 via <gateway> congctl lp
```

Alternatively, LD_PRELOAD a library that calls `setsockopt(..., TCP_CONGESTION, "lp")` on the TCP socket before connecting (probably a good place to do it is by hooking the existing setsockopt (IP_TOS) call that ssh already does), or patch `ssh` to do it by itself.

```c
/* gcc -shared -o force_lp.so force_lp.c */

#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

int setsockopt(int fd, int level, int name, const void *value, socklen_t len)
{
    static int (*real_setsockopt)(int, int, int, const void *, socklen_t);
    int r;

    if (!real_setsockopt)
        real_setsockopt = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "setsockopt");
    
    if ((level == SOL_IP && name == IP_TOS) ||
        (level == SOL_IPV6 && name == IPV6_TCLASS))
    {
        /* This is probably the TCP socket that will be used for SSH. */
        r = real_setsockopt(fd, SOL_TCP, TCP_CONGESTION, "lp", sizeof "lp");
        if (r != 0)
            warn("Could not set congestion control algorithm");
    }

    return real_setsockopt(fd, level, name, value, len);
}
```

Just to point this out, rsync doesn't have a say in the congestion algorithm because it never gets direct access to the TCP socket – it does everything by talking to the `ssh` process via stdio.

Comment: Great answer. I think I'll try with the `LD_PRELOAD` trick you suggested because it looks like it would have the least side-effects. I'll probably need to have additional connections to the same server and adjusting the whole route seems like too big hammer. It would be awesome to have this as an official feature in Linux via `cgroup` or `/proc/<pid>/net/ipv4/tcp_congestion_control`. Having built-in support in ssh would be the second best option.

Comment: I also noticed that there's option `SO_PRIORITY` which would alllow forcing lower priority for the connection on the socket level. Maybe that could be included here, too? The congestion control selection is superior because it also prevents taking bandwidth from other clients in the same network, though. The socket priority might just improve latency of the other processes a little bit.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's useful; it seems that the kernel already sets socket priority according to whatever IP_TOS value is set on the socket, so just adjust `IPToS` in ssh instead. (Though the default IPToS for non-interactive SSH is 'cs1' – which is already the second-lowest, after the very-recently-introduced 'le'.)