# How can I tell ssh to connect using the non-temporary IPv6 address?

Tags: ssh, ipv6, privacy-extensions

IPv6 interfaces (with routable IPs at least) usually have a temporary IP address, which changes frequently and is normally used for outbound connections in order to provide more privacy.

How can I tell ssh to not use this address, but instead bind to the non-temporary one for a given outbound connection attempt?

I know I can use the `-b` option  to bind to a specific IP address, but that means I would have to look up the IP address of the outbound interface first.

Comment: This question should be expanded and improved if you want help. It doesn't clearly say what you want to achieve. It's too vague and open to interpretation. You should clarify and explain, so that people won't have to guess what you want help with. Server config? Client behavior?  What, and why?

Comment: As for why: In one case it’s because a gateway uses the IP address of an inbound ssh connection to open other parts of the network, but there are other reasons to want to have a stable, non-temporary source address when connecting to ssh servers, at the expense of IP address privacy (which often does not matter for ssh).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Linux, ssh would need to call setsockopt(IPV6_ADDR_PREFERENCES) to request a specific address type. (This is not mentioned in Linux setsockopt docs, but the code is present in the kernel and seems to match the RFC 5014 specification.)

Since OpenSSH doesn't have any config options that would let you specify address preferences, it'd have to be a hack like [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1726988/how-to-specify-tcp-congestion-algorithm-to-use-for-my-long-running-rsync-process/1726994) (only with a different sockopt). You can try asking the OpenSSH developers to add such an option, but they generally do not want to add any OS features that OpenBSD doesn't also support.

It's probably easier to script something to get the correct address for `-b`; for example, if you're on Linux you could use `ip | jq`:

```
addr=$(ip -json -6 addr ls dev eno1 scope global \
      | jq -r ".[].addr_info[]|select(.local)|select(.temporary|not)|.local")

ssh -b $addr ...
```

Alternatively – turn off temporary addresses (Privacy Extensions) completely.

But if you want to try your luck with `LD_PRELOAD`, you can test this (I haven't tested it at all; it might very well be that it will be triggered too late to have any effect):

```c
/* gcc -shared -o ipv6pref.so ipv6pref.c */
/* LD_PRELOAD="$HOME/ipv6pref.so" ssh whatever */

#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

int setsockopt(int fd, int level, int name, const void *value, socklen_t len)
{
    static int (*real_setsockopt)(int, int, int, const void *, socklen_t);
    uint32_t flags = IPV6_PREFER_SRC_PUBLIC;
    int r;

    if (!real_setsockopt)
        real_setsockopt = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "setsockopt");
    
    if ((level == SOL_IP && name == IP_TOS) ||
        (level == SOL_IPV6 && name == IPV6_TCLASS))
    {
        /* This is probably the TCP socket that will be used for SSH. */
        r = real_setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_ADDR_PREFERENCES, &flags, sizeof flags);
        if (r != 0)
            warn("Could not set address preference");
    }

    return real_setsockopt(fd, level, name, value, len);
}
```